# Access a GIT raw file programmatically (Java)

Tags: java, git, git-stash

I have a requirement to access the contents file which is on GIT Repo.

- The repo is not public, is there a java library which I can use to ease this task?
- Any code snippet ?

Comment: JGit can most likely do that.

Comment: I need to onlu access a specific file and dont want to clone the entire repo.
Jgit clones the entire repo, which I dont want to.

Also the other issue the repo is secure, want to access just one specific file from the repo.

Comment: So it's "not public"; how _can_ you access it?  With the `git` program?